# XmlStartlet Namespace Issue

Tags: xml, xpath, xml-namespaces, xmlstarlet, xmllint

Have issue with XmlStartlet and namespaces (using windows)
I am running this from command line and **not using xslt**

Please see sample Xml below;

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<BAMDefinition xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/BizTalkServer/2004/10/BAM">
  <Activity xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/BizTalkServer/2004/10/BAM" Name="TEST1" ID="ID85FB3D38A9CB4BF885C6A5BE7EBBE073">
    <Checkpoint Name="ReceivedDt" ID="IDE7FB8E0181894CB6A8F097C746837757" DataType="DATETIME"/>
  </Activity>
  <Activity xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/BizTalkServer/2004/10/BAM" Name="TEST2" ID="ID85FB3D38A9CB4BF885C6A5BE7EBBE074">
    <Checkpoint Name="Filename" ID="IDA65B929E71704F7FA09044CD231044D4" DataType="NVARCHAR" DataLength="255"/>
  </Activity>
</BAMDefinition>
```

I want to either;
delete node that has a xmlns attribute with specific selector attribute @Name="TEST1" using the ed -N
or 
Delete all namespaces to allow me to manipulate Xml
I have tried looking at http://xmlstar.sourceforge.net/doc/UG/ch05s01.html, but this did not work.

I have looked at the documentation;
http://xmlstar.sourceforge.net/doc/UG/xmlstarlet-ug.html#idm47077139518336 (section 1.4 to no avail)
If anyone can suggest a link that would assist or any command line options, I would be obliged

Comment: The links you supplied are using xslt.  I am trying to use this from command line.